# javascript: Shortest code to find object key matching a pattern

Tags: javascript

Consider the object:

```
var myObj = {
  hugeKey1: 'xxx',
  hugeKey2: 'xxx',
  hugeKey3: 'xxx',
  hugeKey4: 'xxx',
  prettyKey1: 'Only one'
};
```

Following is the code for getting a list of all keys with pattern `hugeKey`:

```
var filteredKeySet = _.filter(
    Object.keys(data),
    function (key) {
        if (key.match(/hugeKey/i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

There is only one key named `PrettyKey1`, but this the number at the end is dynamic - it could be `PrettyKey2` as well.

What's the shortest piece of code to find the first key with pattern match?

Something that looks like `Object.keys(myObj).findFirstMatch(/PrettyKey/i);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to previous answers, in case you need to perform such operation frequently and the target object is also changing you could write following utility function:

```
function matchBy(pattern) {
    return obj => Object.keys(obj).find(k => k.match(pattern));
}
```

or

```
function findBy(pattern) {
    return obj => Object.keys(obj).find(k => k.includes(pattern));
}
```

And then use them as :

```
var match = matchBy(/prettyKey/i);
var find = findBy("prettyKey");

....
console.log(match(myObj));
console.log(find(myObj));
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your requirements, this is probably what you need:

```
const firstMatchedKeyNameInObject = Object.keys(myObj).find(keyName => keyName.includes('prettyKey'));
```

Comment: Thanks - Matched Key Name is the requirement

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I'll adjust my answer so it doesn't include the P.S. as it was just to clarify your intent.

Answer (score 1):

From

```
function callback(elm){
    if(elm.match(/prettyKey/i)) return true;
}
Object.keys(myObj).findIndex(callback);
```

to

```
Object.keys(myObj).findIndex(key=>key.match(/PrettyKey/i))
```

or

```
Object.keys(myObj).findIndex(key=>key.includes('prettyKey'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so found a possible answer almost immediately after posting:

`Object.keys(myObj).findIndex(x=>x.match(/PrettyKey/i))`

Just needed to use the `=>` based index search on the keys.

Wonder if there is a faster way of doing this via lodash.